# Rails Credentials Encrypted and Saved but Return Nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null, credentials

I'm following this rails tutorial : [Ruby on Rails for Beginners](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLm8ctt9NhMNV75T9WYIrA6m9I_uw7vS56). I was doing fine until I had to save some credentials in development environment.

I did the following command in the ubuntu console :

```bash
EDITOR="code --wait" rails credentials:edit --environment=development
```

It opened an empty file (number.development.yaml) in which I typed some test data for me to fetch later :

```yaml
 test:
   my_key: "hello"
   another_key: "world"
```

Then I did `ctrl+S`, it saved in `c:/tmp`.

And I closed it so it could be encrypted and saved.

My Ubuntu terminal is telling me that it worked :

```bash
nyc@LAPTOP-IMRKD0GG:/mnt/c/code/sheduled_tweets$ EDITOR="code --wait" rails credentials:edit --environment=development
File encrypted and saved.
```

But then when I try to access the data by going in the console it doesn't work.
Trying various commands to see if I can access the data:

```
Rails.application.credentials
# => #<ActiveSupport::EncryptedConfiguration:0x00007f25d7122cb8
# @config={},
# @content_path=#<Pathname:/mnt/c/code/sheduled_tweets/config/credentials/development.yml.enc>,
# @encryptor=
#  #<ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor:0x00007f25d71221a0
#   @aead_mode=true,
#   @cipher="aes-128-gcm",
#   @on_rotation=nil,
#   @options={:cipher=>"aes-128-gcm"},
#   @rotations=[],
#   @secret="I\x82\xC2\xE2\xEB|)R\xFA+t\xF7<3:\x17",
#   @serializer=Marshal,
#   @sign_secret=nil,
#   @verifier=ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::NullVerifier>,
# @env_key="RAILS_MASTER_KEY",
# @key_file_contents="4982c2e2eb7c2952fa2b74f73c333a17",
# @key_path=#<Pathname:/mnt/c/code/sheduled_tweets/config/credentials/development.key>,
# @options={},
# @raise_if_missing_key=false>

Rails.application.credentials.test
# => nil

Rails.application.credentials.dig(:test)
# => nil

Rails.application.credentials.dig(:test, :my_key)
# => nil

Rails.application.credentials.dig(:test, :another_key)
# => nil
```

As you can see it doesn't look like my test was saved anywhere.

I read and watched many tutorials and guides , watched a bunch of answers to similar issues here on stackoverflow but without any success.

If you have an idea on what I'm doing wrong I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: I couldn't see any issue in your code. However, Have you checked the file again thru editor? Are you able to see the data you entered in the yaml file?

Comment: Since you are seing a begginers tutorial, I am going to have to ask simple questions, have you reopened your rails console? A `reload` won't reload credentials

Comment: And if that still does not work, try supressing the possible problems like: generate the encrypted yml (the ".yml.enc" file), stores the hash, and compares it with the filled credentials hash after you saved it, if the hashes are the same, we know the problem is about saving the credentials, if they are not, then we know the problem is trying to access them, you could use git for that comparission as well

Comment: Yes ma, I when I reopen the saved yaml files I can see the data I saved in it.

Comment: Yes saviu-u I reopenend the console , also reloaded the server without any success.
However as you suggested I compared the 2 hash in the development.yml.enc before and after ecrypting and saving and they are indeed identical so the issue is probably about saving/encrypting the new credentials.

Comment: I think the issue might be tied to the fact that you're using `test` as the root key of your YAML. Try anything else such as `foo`.

Comment: I tried max thanks, but it didnt work unfortunetly.

Comment: Since you said it didn't seems to save, try using another editor as nano, see if it solves, you know it will work if it you re run the command, and you see the changes persisted as well as the hash being different

Comment: Thank you so much saviu-u , it actually worked using nano.
When I openend the original default credentials it showed me the default key/values : 
aws:
  access_key_id: 123
  secret_access_key: 456
I never had those with VSCode.
And when saving different values I could find them in the console with Rails.application.credentials.aws
I must have a bad configuration on my VSCode or something. 
In any case my problem is solved many thanks to you friend !

Comment: Hey, I am happy I could help, I think the fact that you are using another mount to store the rails project (/mnt folder) might impact on access issues or maybe vscode just can't access files on other mounts that simply, I recommend you to move the project to another folder inside your system domain just to see if that fixes (/home), running code as sudo or just checking the file permissions (docker users also tend to have issues with file permissions), if you really want to use vscode, I recommend you to create another stack overflow question so it's a different topic, Wish you the best, man!